# Opencart - check image for print upon upload

Tags: imagemagick, opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.6 and have written various codes to check the DPI of an image and resize the image to let the user know if they have the right file.

Resize image: http://zing-cards.com/imagetest2.php (orig is 640x480)

Check DPI: http://zing-cards.com/imagedpi1.php

As you can see they work on my server.

Resize code:

```php
<?php
$photo="/home/tcsdesig/public_html/zing/flower.jpg";
$cmd = "/usr/bin/convert $photo -thumbnail 300x182 JPG:-"; //Convert image to smaller size for preview

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
passthru($cmd, $retval);

?>
```

Check DPI

```php
<?php

header("Content-type: text/html");

    $photoPath1 = "flower1.jpg";

    ...

    $dpiCommand = "/usr/bin/identify";
    if (!is_executable($dpiCommand)) die("Sorry, can't execute $dpiCommand!");
    $output = shell_exec("$dpiCommand -format '%x' $photoPath1");
    $dpi = explode(' ',trim($output));  //breaks up the result to get the number out (72 PixelsPerInch = 72)
    $dpiInt = (int)$dpi[0];  //changes the number to an integer (72 PixelsPerInch = 72)
    if ($dpiInt < 300) { //check if PPI is less than 300.
        echo "You should increase your PPI (DPI) for best printing quality. <br/><br/> Your current PPI is " . $output . "<br/>";
    } else { 
        echo "Congratulations! You're image is optimized for best printing quality.";   
    }

?>
```

For the resize I want OC to upload the original and then resize it, upload a resized copy then display that copy. I started by just trying to display a resized copy. In my controller => product.php I changed the code to look like this:

```php
if (!$json && is_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name']) && file_exists($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            $file = basename($filename) . '.' . md5(mt_rand());

            // Hide the uploaded file name so people can not link to it directly.

            $json['file'] = $this->encryption->encrypt($file);



            move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'], DIR_DOWNLOAD . $file);

            /* RESIZE IMAGE */
            $resizeCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";
            if (!is_executable($resizeCommand)) die("Sorry, can't execute $resizeCommand!");
            $resizeOutput = shell_exec("$resizeCommand basename($filename) -thumbnail 300x182 JPG:-");
            /* END RESIZE IMAGE */

            $json['thumb'] = $resizeOutput; //this gets displayed on the product.tpl page in a div set aside for the image.

            $json['success'] = 'The file "' . basename($filename) . '" has been uploaded.';
        }
```

The result comes back as null and I don't get the error message to see if the resizeCommand is executable.

For more info on this code you can see my related post: [Opencart - Customer uploads different files to one product with different responses from the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848908/opencart-customer-uploads-different-files-to-one-product-with-different-respon)

Am I on the right track? Is this were I should be adding this code or should it go in the product.php?

Could it be something with my php.ini or index file as mentioned here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324895/image-magick-php-extension-is-installed-but-showing-error-class-imagick-not-foun?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to resize image in opencart way, then you can use the below code in your controller file:

```
$this->load->model('tool/image'); 

if ($this->data['profile_pic']) {
$this->data['image'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data['profile_pic'], 320, 240); //320 width, 240 height
} else {
$this->data['image'] = '';
}
```

where `$this->data['profile_pic']` - contains the path relative to `image` folder.

Have a nice day !

Comment: The problem is that we want to be able to show the user what his/her image will look like when printed. We need to have it a specific size (300 x 900) and DPI/PPI (300 PPI) so that when it prints it will look good. 

We need to first check the PPI and display a warning that it is not high enough. Then we want to process the image by resizing it to 300x900 at 300PPI to show them what it will look like. If they want to keep it they can. The other option is just to check the PPI and if it is low not allow them to upload.