# Opencart 2.0 Thumbnail image for uploaded file option

Tags: opencart

I am trying to add a thumbnail image of the uploaded file on a product option.
I have looked around stackoverflow.com and found the below page but that is for OpenCart 1.5.6

can your anyone tell me how to create a thumbnail for file upload in OpenCart 2.0

I have tried but OpenCart file upload uses ajax file upload and a lot of difference in OpenCart 1.5.6 and 2.0 versions
if you see the below script this is used in open cart 1.5.6 in file name "Product.tpl"

```
`<script type="text/javascript"><!--
new AjaxUpload('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>', {
    action: 'index.php?route=product/product/upload',
    name: 'file',
    autoSubmit: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').after('<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);
    },
    onComplete: function(file, json) {
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').attr('disabled', false);
        
        $('.error').remove();
        
        if (json['success']) {
            alert(json['success']);
            
            $('input[name=\'option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]\']').attr('value', json['file']);
        }
        
        if (json['error']) {
            $('#option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').after('<span class="error">' + json['error'] + '</span>');
        }
        
        $('.loading').remove(); 
    }
});
//--></script>`
```

if you see below script this is used in OpenCart 2.0 in Product.tpl

```
`<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-cart').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-cart').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                        if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                            element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                        } else {
                            element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                    $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
                }

                // Highlight any found errors
                $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
```

I was trying to generate Thumbnail within open cart 1.5.6  with help of this link

[Opencart - Customer uploads different files to one product with different responses from the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848908/opencart-customer-uploads-different-files-to-one-product-with-different-respon)

it was working fine
but it is not working in OpenCart 2.0 because the script was complete different can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOR 2.0 vresion : 2.2 till   IF IMAGE MANAGERN UPLOGIN NOT WORKING**

> use this code modifyed By VinaySingh43@gmail.com

### Path : admin / controller / common/filemanager.php

```html
<?php

class ControllerCommonFileManager extends Controller {

public function index() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$filter_name = rtrim(str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..', '*'), '', $this->request->get['filter_name']), '/');

} else {

$filter_name = null;

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {

$page = $this->request->get['page'];

} else {

$page = 1;

}



$data['images'] = array();



$this->load->model('tool/image');



// Get directories

$directories = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);



if (!$directories) {

$directories = array();

}



// Get files

// $files = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);



$files1 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpg');

if (!$files1) {

$files1 = array();

}



$files2 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpeg');

if (!$files2) {

$files2 = array();

}



$files3 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPG');

if (!$files3) {

$files3 = array();

}



$files4 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.png');

if (!$files4) {

$files4 = array();

}



$files5 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPEG');

if (!$files5) {

$files5 = array();

}



$files6 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.PNG');

if (!$files6) {

$files6 = array();

}



$files7 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.GIF');

if (!$files7) {

$files7 = array();

}

$files8 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.gif');

if (!$files8) {

$files8 = array();

}





$files = array_merge($files1, $files2,$files3,$files4,$files5,$files6,$files7,$files8);





// Merge directories and files

$images = array_merge($directories, $files);



// Get total number of files and directories

$image_total = count($images);



// Split the array based on current page number and max number of items per page of 10

$images = array_splice($images, ($page - 1) * 16, 16);



foreach ($images as $image) {

$name = str_split(basename($image), 14);



if (is_dir($image)) {

 $url = '';



 if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

     $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

 }



 if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

     $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

 }



 $data['images'][] = array(

     'thumb' => '',

     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),

     'type'  => 'directory',

     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),

     'href'  => $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&directory=' . urlencode(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/'))) . $url, true)

 );

} elseif (is_file($image)) {

 // Find which protocol to use to pass the full image link back

 if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {

     $server = HTTPS_CATALOG;

 } else {

     $server = HTTP_CATALOG;

 }



 $data['images'][] = array(

     'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100),

     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),

     'type'  => 'image',

     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),

     'href'  => $server . 'image/' . utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE))

 );

}

}



$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');



$data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');

$data['text_confirm'] = $this->language->get('text_confirm');



$data['entry_search'] = $this->language->get('entry_search');

$data['entry_folder'] = $this->language->get('entry_folder');



$data['button_parent'] = $this->language->get('button_parent');

$data['button_refresh'] = $this->language->get('button_refresh');

$data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');

$data['button_folder'] = $this->language->get('button_folder');

$data['button_delete'] = $this->language->get('button_delete');

$data['button_search'] = $this->language->get('button_search');



$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$data['directory'] = urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);

} else {

$data['directory'] = '';

}



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$data['filter_name'] = $this->request->get['filter_name'];

} else {

$data['filter_name'] = '';

}



// Return the target ID for the file manager to set the value

if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$data['target'] = $this->request->get['target'];

} else {

$data['target'] = '';

}



// Return the thumbnail for the file manager to show a thumbnail

if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$data['thumb'] = $this->request->get['thumb'];

} else {

$data['thumb'] = '';

}



// Parent

$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$pos = strrpos($this->request->get['directory'], '/');



if ($pos) {

 $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(substr($this->request->get['directory'], 0, $pos));

}

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$data['parent'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);



// Refresh

$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$url .= '&directory=' . urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);



$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['directory'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

}



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$url .= '&filter_name=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['filter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$pagination = new Pagination();

$pagination->total = $image_total;

$pagination->page = $page;

$pagination->limit = 16;

$pagination->url = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', true);



$data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();



$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/filemanager', $data));

}



public function upload() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



// Check its a directory

if (!is_dir($directory)) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');

}



if (!$json) {

if (!empty($this->request->files['file']['name']) && is_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'])) {

 // Sanitize the filename

 $filename = basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->files['file']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));



 // Validate the filename length

 if ((utf8_strlen($filename) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($filename) > 255)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filename');

 }



 // Allowed file extension types

 $allowed = array(

     'jpg',

     'jpeg',

     'gif',

     'png'

 );



 if (!in_array(utf8_strtolower(utf8_substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)), $allowed)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');

 }



 // Allowed file mime types

 $allowed = array(

     'image/jpeg',

     'image/pjpeg',

     'image/png',

     'image/x-png',

     'image/gif'

 );



 if (!in_array($this->request->files['file']['type'], $allowed)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');

 }



 // Return any upload error

 if ($this->request->files['file']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload_' . $this->request->files['file']['error']);

 }

} else {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload');

}

}



if (!$json) {

move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'], $directory . '/' . $filename);



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_uploaded');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}



public function folder() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



// Check its a directory

if (!is_dir($directory)) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');

}



if (!$json) {

// Sanitize the folder name

$folder = str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['folder'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));



// Validate the filename length

if ((utf8_strlen($folder) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($folder) > 128)) {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_folder');

}



// Check if directory already exists or not

if (is_dir($directory . '/' . $folder)) {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');

}

}



if (!$json) {

mkdir($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);

chmod($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_directory');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}



public function delete() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



if (isset($this->request->post['path'])) {

$paths = $this->request->post['path'];

} else {

$paths = array();

}



// Loop through each path to run validations

foreach ($paths as $path) {

$path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');



// Check path exsists

if ($path == DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_delete');



 break;

}

}



if (!$json) {

// Loop through each path

foreach ($paths as $path) {

 $path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');



 // If path is just a file delete it

 if (is_file($path)) {

     unlink($path);



 // If path is a directory beging deleting each file and sub folder

 } elseif (is_dir($path)) {

     $files = array();



     // Make path into an array

     $path = array($path . '*');



     // While the path array is still populated keep looping through

     while (count($path) != 0) {

         $next = array_shift($path);



         foreach (glob($next) as $file) {

             // If directory add to path array

             if (is_dir($file)) {

                 $path[] = $file . '/*';

             }



             // Add the file to the files to be deleted array

             $files[] = $file;

         }

     }



     // Reverse sort the file array

     rsort($files);



     foreach ($files as $file) {

         // If file just delete

         if (is_file($file)) {

             unlink($file);



         // If directory use the remove directory function

         } elseif (is_dir($file)) {

             rmdir($file);

         }

     }

 }

}



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_delete');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works and I have modified as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but may this is still help.

you just have to add this line to the upload controller:

```
$json['file'] = "system/upload/" . $file;
```

and the following line to product.tpl:

```
$(node).parent().find('input').after('<img class="text-danger"><img src=' + json['file'] + '></div>');
```

and after that maybe some styling elements.